# SQL Server version of MySQL's group_concat and escaped strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-express

I only have the Express versions of MS SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio. Given that I can't create a SQL Server project and therefore CLR solutions are out of the question, I've attempted to use

```
select col1, stuff( ( select ' ' + col2
from StrConcat t1
where t2.col1 = t1.col1
for xml path('')
),1,1,'')
from StrConcat t2
group by col1
order by col1
```

to get a row concatenated col2. col2 is a varchar field with some control characters like *&* and *\n*. When it is concatenated with the above SQL, it appears to escape those control characters ie. *&* becomes 
 & amp ; and *\n* becomes &#xOD, which is not what I want it to do. Given that the col1 and concatenated field is going to be used to update another table, what is the best way to get the concatenated field in its unescaped original form or is there none and the only way is to resort to external code?

The table schema looks like this:
StrConcat (id int primary key, col1 int, txt varchar(80)) 
col1 has an index on it, txt should be grouped by col1, ordered by id within the group.

Comment: The `for xml` part adds xml escaping to your response, that is (one of the) downsides of using this method. I'm not sure if it's easy to omit that problem.

Comment: Good point. So I guess the real question is, what is a better solution that will achieve the same thing without that downside.

Comment: You could try using a comma, and then use the REPLACE function to replace the comma with markup you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is, of course, [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx).  If it didn't escape this way, the query could output invalid XML.

If you need to get an unescaped value within SQL Server, then you'll have to use one of the [other concatenation methods](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) (recursive CTE is usually the next-most efficient after CLR aggregate and `FOR XML`, but hardest to write).

Of course, if this is being passed directly to an application, it will be much easier to unescape it there, i.e. using the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class in .NET.

Comment: Interestingly, I did try recursive CTE, which is taking 48 minutes and counting to run. So it sounds like there is no easy way to do it within SQL Server short of resorting to code.

Comment: @TheObserver: Yikes. How many rows are you trying to concatenate? Is the data indexed properly? The only other thing that might be faster is the `UPDATE` trick, but if you want it ordered then you'd have to select into a temporary table / table variable first.

Comment: 1.6 million records, variable number of rows to concatenate per col1 value. col1 has an index on it. And the field to be concatenated do need to be ordered by the table's primary key. What is the update trick?

Comment: @TheObserver: The index needs to cover the output columns in order to be effective. Make sure you `INCLUDE` the column being concatenated.  As for the update trick, it's the thing they tell you not to do at the end of the second link I posted ("Scalar UDF with T-SQL Update Extension"). It's theoretically possible for Microsoft to change the implementation in a future version of SQL server and break that, but it hasn't happened in 10 years, so you're probably safe...